# Atom editor - align menu to left

Tags: text, editor, text-editor, atom-editor, text-alignment

I installed Atom editor on Windows 10.
When i open the program, the top menu bar is align to right.
**I want it to align left**.
I tried to find some configuration in the setting option on the menu - 
but didnt found nothing that solve that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Atom uses CSS to style itself.
You are probably using an RTL OS, which causes it to automatically align the menus to the right.

You can find a complete guide on customization in their [docs](https://atom.io/docs/latest/using-atom-basic-customization).